# Linq IList interfaces vs concrete

Tags: c#, linq

Now with

```
IList<string> listOfStrings = (new string[] {  "bob","mary"});
```

We can not preform

```
listOfStrings.ToList().ForEach(i => i.DoSome(i)));
```

We need to reshape to the concrete implementation of the Interface

```
List<string> listOfStrings = ((new string[] {  "bob","mary"}).ToLIst();
```

Then we can do a for each

```
listOfStrings.ForEach(i => i.DoSome(i)));
```

Is this because the foreach operator does not work with the IList Interface and why is this ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not using the `foreach` operator - you're using a `ForEach` *method*, which is declared on `List<T>` [(here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) and also for [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx). There's no such extension method on `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. You could write one, but personally I'd use a real `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var text in listOfStrings)
{
    ...
}
```

See Eric Lippert's blog [post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for thoughts that are rather more lucid than mine.

Answer (score 3):

The `ForEach` method is [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx).  It is not a method defined on `IList<T>`.

---

However, your first example actually does work:

```
listOfStrings.ToList().ForEach(i => i.DoSome(i)));
```

The [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method returns a `List<T>`, which allows the above to actually work fine.

You could not do, however:

// Will fail at compile time
    listOfStrings.ForEach(i => i.DoSome(i)));

As this is using the `IList<T>` directly, which doesn't have a ForEach method defined.